# How to display .toggle or .Animate to all connected browser sessions using Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

But how do you show the interaction of clicking on an element that toggles or animates?
The meteor checkers example:
http://checkers.meteor.com/

In the example below, I would like for every browser that's connected to the Meteor server to be able to see when one of the other browsers makes the shape change.

https://jsfiddle.net/qh2jyL3b/

HTML:

```
<div class="square"></div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 10px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".square").click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass("circle");
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store click state in Meteor.Collection. Changes in collections propagate reactively for all connected clients. Just create separate document for each square and save state here. Then you can create helper that displays correct class name depending on db items.

For example you can do this this way:

For each chess-table you can create separate document
on server side:

`ChessTableCell = new Mongo.Collection('chesstablecell');`

Then you can store state of each cell in each of this document. So initially you can insert

```
ChessTableCell.insert({name: 'a1', state: false);
ChessTableCell.insert({name: 'a2', state: false);

...etc
```

And on your client side you have access to cells states like this:

`ChessTableCell.findOne({name: 'a1'}).state;`

And on click you just need to toggle state of clicked cell. You can do it in a following way:

```
Template.chessboard.events({//or whatever your template is called like
    'click .cell': function(e,t) {
      var cellName = $(e.target).data('name'); //if you specify cell name in your html in data-name attribute
      var cellValue = ChessTableCell.findOne({name: cellName}).state;
      //here you can update the value
      ChessTableCell.update({name: cellValue}, {$set: { state: !cellValue}});
    }
});
```

Then state will change reactively on every connected client.
Of course you need to reflect those changes in your html like this:

```
{{#each ChessTableCells}}
  <div class="cell {{#if state}}active{{/if}}" data-name="{{name}}"></div>
{{/each}}
```

And in your client code:

```
Template.chessboard.helpers({
  ChessTableCells: function() { return ChessTableCell.find({}); }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much MatiK. I will look into Meteor.Collections and see what I can find out. Do you mind if I message you in like a week or so if I am still having trouble? I can send my code at that time to see if it helps.

Comment: I am still having some trouble finding how to store a click state in Meteor.Collections. I have been going over the beginner tutorial "Todo APP" on meteor.com's tutorial section. And can kind of see how they are storing the checked/unchecked state in a mongoDB. Every client connected can see when one of the other clients checks a box. I feel like I am so close! lol

Comment: I added examples for you to make it work. You just need to put it in your code and style it or wrap with proper svg :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the example MatiK. When I get off work I will check it out.

Comment: Let me know :) And if it helps you please accept answer and upvote it :)

Comment: I definitely will. I am probably going to start fresh and incorporate what I learn from your example into it. If I am still struggling I can link my code.